# Jquery Trim all spaces from variable

Tags: jquery, string, variables, replace

On a click I store a variable. I would like to then trim that variable for  all whitespace. I am getting an error when I to simply console.log the new variable.

```
var songToTrim = $(this).html();
console.log(songToTrim);
var songToPlay = songToTrim.replace(/ /g,'');
console.log(songToPlay);
```

For bonus points if you can add how to make sure the variable is converted to all lowercase that would be huge. If not it'll still work. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you simply use `$.trim(songToTrim)`

Comment: @Kartikeya `$.trim` trims whitespace from the ends, I think stripping all whitespace is the intent.

Comment: Which error? Also try .text().toLowerCase().replace...

Comment: Where is this code run. What is the actual error?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Im trying to get the code up on fiddle or something. Its kinda complicated (for me) with handlebar templates and JSON file so it's taking me a while. Worst case I will put it up on my server

Comment: @mplungjan I am getting this error on the second console.log. The first variable works fine

Uncaught ReferenceError: consle is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

Code:

```
 $("#test").on('click', function(){
    var songToTrim = $(this).html();
   var trm  = songToTrim.replace(/ /g,'');
   var songToPlay = trm.toLowerCase();
    });
```

Use `.toLowerCase()` to convert your variable to Lower Case.

The error you are getting is because you have a *typo* in your code somewhere. You have misspelled `Console` as `Consle`.

Find it and correct it.

Here is a working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9e6ghry/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
var str = songToTrim.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
var lower = str.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: I am not receiving an error anymore but the variable still has white space

Comment: try using replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')