# How to remove space in jquery masking

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui, jquery-mask

User copy input string: "A344 34"  //string with space

expected output value in textbox:  "A34434"

Problem: with below code: getting result as : "A344"   //and skip the remain chars.

```
$('#pmField').mask('XXXXXX', {
    translation: {
        'X': {
            pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]/, optional: true
        }
    }
});
```

//Input textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this with javascript which is very simple using the code below
which i have edited to get variable displayed in a text box

source: [Remove spaces in a Javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613680/remove-spaces-in-a-javascript-variable)

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" value="">

    <script>

    var a = "A344 34";
    a=a.replace(/\s/g, "");
    alert(a);

    var test = "Hello";
     document.getElementById("mytext").value = a;
    </script>
```

also if you insist on using jquery, then similar solution has been  implemented by @VSri58 as per the code below

H el lo

```
        $("#test").on('click', function(){
            //var songToTrim = $(this).html();
var songToTrim = 'A344 34';
           var trm  = songToTrim.replace(/ /g,'');
    // try this
    document.getElementById("mytext1").value = trm;
        alert(trm);
           var songToPlay = trm.toLowerCase();
            });
```

you can customize the code to suit your need

source for the above code: [Jquery Trim all spaces from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415631/jquery-trim-all-spaces-from-variable)

**Masking Example**

```
  var value = "1234567"
var formatted = value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/,"$1-$2");
alert(formatted);
```

source: [Mask javascript variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650197/mask-javascript-variable-value)

Comment: How to do while paste into textbox.

Comment: do you mean to have the value displayed in a textbox inputs

Comment: I have edited the answer to display result in a form inputs

Comment: Yes, when copy from any source and just paste to textbox then, textbox should only take non space char. Like-  KLP 03K then textbox should be KLP03K and skip the field. Max lenght of textbox is 6. How to do Masking or any way to do that.

Comment: Have tested the above script. It will convert KLP 03K to non sapce char KLP03K. If you want to do masking. if you want to do masking,  I have updated the script with example on how to do masking